# Suggestions for aesthetically pleasing statistics applications or screensavers?

Tags: display, statistics

I've got a small 14" LCD display on my home server that I keep attached for whenever I want to access the console directly (I usually connect via RDP). This is connected to a box running Windows 2008 R2.

I'd like to keep the LCD on and have it display useful stats - e.g. CPU temp, drive space free, memory/cpu load, pagefile size,  incoming/outgoing IO, # of connections, etc etc etc.

Does anyone know of a screensaver or desktop customization app that will give me an aesthetically pleasing display of all this stuff?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of a screensaver which would probably be better, but the first thing that comes to mind is [Microsoft \ Sysinternals BGinfo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897557.aspx).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [Rainmeter](http://rainmeter.net/) - which is a skinnable and highly customisable application that can show information on your available system resources and battery power as well as the weather and RSS feeds.

[image: example Rainmeter skin (Enigma)]